# C++:Adding an element to a tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, typelist

I am going through the custom implementation for tuples , which is described in C++ template second edition.
I need a help to understand how the `pushFront` actually work. What are the steps that compiler does in order to put the new element in the start of the tuple

```
template <typename... Elements>
class Typelist
{
};

template <typename... Elements, typename NewElement>
class PushFrontT<Typelist<Elements...>, NewElement> {
 public:
  using Type = Typelist<NewElement, Elements...>;
};

template <typename List, typename NewElement>
using PushFront = typename PushFrontT<List, NewElement>::Type;

template <typename... Types, typename V>
PushFront<Tuple<Types...>, V> 
pushFront(Tuple<Types...> const& tuple, V const& value)
{
  return PushFront<Tuple<Types...>, V>(value, tuple);
}
```

In the above piece of code, how actually , does the last line work?
"`PushFront<Tuple<Types...>, V>(value, tuple);`"

How from `PushFront<Tuple<Types...>, V>` , we get a tuple in which pass as head the value and as tail the existing tuple?

Comment: This would appear to be a somewhat peculiar book. The thing here is that `PushFront` is, for some reason, a _class_. So `PushFront<Tuple<Types...>, V>(value, tuple);` is actually the constructor for the `PushFront` class, which isn't shown but which presumably initializes all the values.

Comment: To be more explicit, when we unwind the aliases, we see that `PushFront<Tuple<Types...>, V>` is another way of saying `Typelist<V, Types...>`, so invoking the `PushFront` constructor is actually invoking the `Typelist` constructor which we don't see.

Comment: What's happening with the types, here, is fairly simple. What is unclear is that something somewhere needs to unpack the `tuple` parameter, in order to reassemble the new tuple. There's nothing in the shown code that appears to do that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik,this is my question how the the tuple parameter is unpacked

Comment: That's a very good question. There's nothing in the shown code that does that. Perhaps there's something else, in any code that you did not show here, that's a part of the same example; but nobody can explain code that's not shown.

Comment: Are all these levels of `using` actually necessary, because as far as I can tell `PushFront<Tuple<Types...>, V>` ultimately unwinds to `Typelist<V, Types...>` and I don't understand why you couldn't just say that directly or how that's any less readable. (If the point is to show what kinds of `using` statement are syntactically correct and what their semantic content is, I suppose it makes sense, but it does mean figuring out what's actually happening is obfuscated.)

Comment: That being said this doesn't even compile for me (even before the fact that there's no definition for `Tuple`) because you can't have parameter packs not at the end of the parameter list for a template class and a template argument isn't allowed in a declaration of a primary template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I scratched my head so much reading that example that I went and hunted down [the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714121). The book is *not* full of incomprehensible examples, but they're spread out and incrementally implemented. Only a few are shown in the OP's question.

The first part involving is showing how to use partial specialization to push a type to a variadic utility struct called `Typelist`:

```cpp
template <typename... Elements>
class Typelist {};

template<typename List, typename NewElement>
class PushFrontT;

template<typename... Elements, typename NewElement>
class PushFrontT<Typelist<Elements...>, NewElement> { ... };
```

Later on the book implements a full `Tuple` class that includes this constructor:

```cpp
Tuple(Head const& head, Tuple<Tail...> const& tail)
```

And adds a `PushFrontT` specialization just for `Tuple`:

```cpp
template<typename... Types, typename Element>
class PushFrontT<Tuple<Types...>, Element> { ... };
```

So... the answer is that `Tuple` has a convenient constructor to copy a tuple and add an element to the front, and a utility class that uses [partial template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) to unpack the type list of the tuple and add a type to the front. The OP seemed to reach that conclusion in their answer, but I thought this context would be helpful for anyone who stumbled on this question and got confused like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a partial  template specialization is needed

```
// add element to the front:
template<typename... Types, typename Element>
class PushFrontT<Tuple<Types...>, Element> {
 public:
  using Type = Tuple<Element, Types...>;
};
```